# How to update a GORM one-to-one association?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have the following one-to-one bidirectional relationship:

```
class Face {
    static hasOne = [nose: Nose]
}

class Nose {
    static belongsTo = [face: Face]
}
```

I also have the following in my integration test.

```
void testSomething() {
    Face face = new Face()
    Nose nose = new Nose()

    face.nose = nose

    face.save()
}
```

Is there a way to give the face a new nose?  I've run out ideas to try.  None of them work

I tried giving the face a new nose.

```
face.nose = new Nose()
face.save()
```

But that didn't work.  So I thought maybe I have to delete the old nose first (to prevent multiple noses belonging to the same face).

```
nose.delete()
face.nose = new Nose()
face.save()
```

I even tried using the updateable property.

```
class Face {
    static hasOne = [nose: Nose]

    static mapping = {
        nose updateable: true
    }
}
```

And the nullable property.

```
class Nose {
    static belongsTo = [face: Face]

    static mapping = {
        face nullable: true
    }
}
```

Nothing works.  The only thing that does work is creating a completely new face, which I would prefer not to do.  Suppose the Face model has many properties and I wanted to change just one of them.  In order to do that, I'd have to copy all of the old properties into the new Face and then change the one.  Why can't I just do face.nose = new Nose()?

UPDATE 11/12/2013

The following does what I want:

```
class Face {
    Nose nose
}

class Nose {
    static belongsTo = [face: Face]
}
```

With this, I can change the nose on a face.  Interestingly, it can do everything that the first configuration can do too.  That is, they can both do cascading saves and deletes from face to nose.

```
void testCascadingSavesAndDeletesFromFaceToNose() {
    assert Face.count() == 0
    assert Nose.count() == 0

    Face face = new Face(nose: new Nose())
    assert face.save() != null

    assert Face.count() == 1
    assert Nose.count() == 1

    face.delete()

    assert Face.count() == 0
    assert Nose.count() == 0
}
```

They can also both obtain information about the other side of the relationship.

```
void testSimpleSave() {
    Face face = new Face()
    Nose nose = new Nose()

    face.nose = nose
    face.save()

    println "face = ${face}"
    println "nose = ${nose}"
    println "face.nose = ${face.nose}"
    println "nose.face = ${nose.face}"
}
```

Comment: What didn't work when you did face.nose = new Nose()?

Comment: face.nose = new Nose()
    face.save()

Comment: Did you get any error or the relation wasn't updated?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I meant to say: When I try to save the face it tells me that the new nose is unsaved.

Stackoverflow automatically added my comment when I hit the enter key.

Answer (score 2):

Gorm need to have the new object persisted before adding the relationship with an existing object, so in your case try:

```
Nose newNose = new Nose()
newNose.save()
face.nose = newNose
face.save()
```

This wasn't required the first time you instantiate a `face` and adding a `nose` because the face wasn't persisted yet and Gorm is able to persist in cascade.

Comment: ~ Test ~

    void testSomething() {
        Face face = new Face()
        Nose nose = new Nose()

        face.nose = nose
        face.save()

        Nose newNose = new Nose()
        newNose.save()

        face.nose = newNose
        face.save()

        println "face = ${face}"
        println "nose = ${nose}"
        println "newNose = ${newNose}"
        println "face.nose = ${face.nose}"
   }

~ Result ~

face = model.Face : 1
nose = model.Nose : 1
newNose = model.Nose : (unsaved)
face.nose = model.Nose : (unsaved)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to make :

```
nose.delete(flush: true, failOnError: true)
face.nose = new Nose(flush: true, failOnError: true)
face.save()
```

Doc here : http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html

Comment: ~ Test ~

    void testSomething() {
        Face face = new Face()
        Nose nose = new Nose()

        face.nose = nose
        face.save()

        nose.delete(flush: true, failOnError: true)
      
        face.nose = new Nose(flush: true, failOnError: true)
        face.save()

        println "face = ${face}"
        println "nose = ${nose}"
        println "newNose = ${newNose}"
        println "face.nose = ${face.nose}"
    }

Comment: ~ Result ~

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [model.Nose#1]; nested exception is org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [model.Nose#1]
 at itest.DummyTests.testSomething(DummyTests.groovy:18)
Caused by: org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [model.Nose#1]